# Not able to save generated pdf on my remote server

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to save generated pdf in custom folder but its not saving. I want to pdf to send as attachment in email 
 Here is my code generate and save pdf

```
public function email($timestamp=0, $load_id=0, $type=0){
    $this->load->library('tcpdf/Pdf');
    $pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'LETTER', true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetTitle('Document');
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(10);
    $pdf->SetLeftMargin(10);
    $pdf->SetRightMargin(10);
    $pdf->SetTopMargin(10);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 25);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Author');
    $pdf->SetDisplayMode('real', 'default');
    $pdf->Write(5, 'Cal Sierra Load Document'); // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();
    //         $carriers = $this->admin_model->getCarriers(array(), array(), 0,0,1,"","","",1);
    $load=$this->admin_model->getLoad($load_id);
    $pickupDrops=$this->admin_model->getPickupDrops(0,0,1,0,$load_id);
    $loadPickups=array();
    $loadDrops=array();
    if(!empty($pickupDrops)){
        foreach($pickupDrops as $row){
            if($row['type']==1)
                $loadPickups[]=$row;
                else
                    $loadDrops[]=$row;
        }
    }

    $data['load'] = $load;
    $data['loadPickups'] = $loadPickups;
    $data['loadDrops'] = $loadDrops;
    //         $data['carriers'] = $carriers;
    $data['settings'] = $this->settings_model->getSettingsFile();
    $data['currentTime'] =  $timestamp;

    //         echo "<pre>";
    //         print_r($data);
    //         exit();

    switch ($type) {
        case 1:
            $html = $this->load->view('documents/doc1', $data, true);
            break;
        case 2:
            $html = $this->load->view('documents/doc2', $data, true);
            break;
        case 3:
            $html = $this->load->view('documents/doc3', $data, true);
            break;
        default:
    }

    $pdf->Output('custom'.'Document.pdf', 'F');
    $this->Output("custom");

    exit();
}
```

I am not sure where put my folder to pdf i am also adding my folder layout picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUadw.png

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a more complete path to the output function. Something like:

```
$pdf->output(FCPATH . "my/directory/path/" . "pdfName.pdf", 'F');
```

Comment: $pdf->Output(FCPATH . 'home/cal_user/calsierra/uploads/docs/" . "Document.pdf', 'F');
        
        
        exit();

Comment: I added like this but it just open the new window without saving the pdf

Comment: Make sure your path is correct. It may help to var_dump(FCPATH) so that you see where it is going. Just a note, if you are not trying to save this in your applications directory you won't be able to use FCPATH. You will have to write the full path yourself.

Comment: finally got it working    
   $filename = 'Document.pdf';
        $pdfFilePath = "/var/www/html/calsierra/uploads/docs/$filename";


        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
        
        $pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, 'F');