# file location to save pdf on my dev server

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I cannot figure out the file location to save pdf on my dev server. I am trying to save it in uploads folder in my project but it is not saving.

```
 $filename= "Document.pdf";
    $filelocation = $_ENV["App_ENV"]."/uploads/docs";
    $fileNL = $filelocation. "/".$filename;
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    $pdf->Output($fileNL, 'F');


    exit();
```

Can someone help please [Image contains the my project folder layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3fLu.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What's in `$_ENV["App_ENV"]`?  Generally `TCPDF` and other file based operations will be looking for an absolute file path. Such as `__DIR__ . '/' . $_ENV['App_ENV'];`

Answer (score 0):

Your not being very specific by saying 'it's not saving', but I will assume there's no file in the dir after upload and your app gives you nothing. But have you checked the error log of your webserver?

A quick determination of the right permissions is right after determining `$filelocation`, check for the correct permissions with [is_writable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) and exit with a message on screen if not.

**Mind you**: this addition is for you only, so just to determine if it's the permissions. Take it away right after testing.

Comment: I allowed the permission  when I click on the link to save pdf on remote server it opens new window and gives no error in console

Comment: //         $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
        $pdf->Output('/home/cal_user/calsierra/uploads/docs/Document.pdf', 'F');
        
        
        exit();
    }

Comment: here is the link to my code question I asked it includes whole code to my function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53232712/not-able-to-save-generated-pdf-on-my-remote-server

Comment: $pdf->Output('/home/cal_user/calsierra/uploads/docs/Document.pdf', 'F'); exit(); } Only made change to last line to give the file absolute path